# INSERT ... SELECT to same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a number of columns. For each row, I'd like to select three columns (`PAR_BOOK, PAR_PAGE, PAR_LINE`) and concatenate the contents of those three columns into a new fourth column (APN).

So, if PAR_BOOK=0108, PAR_PAGE=291 and PAR_LINE=07, APN should be 010829107

Make sense?

But, I'm unsure of what query I should use to do this. I need the results stored back in the same table as it needs to be ultimately exported out as a csv to work with the program that's going to map the data.

Comment: Show your query. Inserting into the same table is no problem at all as MySQL holds the selected rows in a temporary table.

Comment: Why do you want to store that value in the first place? Information that can be reconstructed based on the existing data should not be stored. You could create a view to achieve this.

Comment: Not that I should have to explain myself, but it's being exported as a csv for use in a mapping application. All of which I explained above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your fourth column is already in the table, you would use the following update query:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET APN = CONCAT(PAR_BOOK, PAR_PAGE, PAR_LINE)
```

If your fourth column is not present in the table yet, you should use the `ALTER TABLE` statement to add it first before running the `UPDATE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD APN VARCHAR(256) NULL
```

Comment: I tried the command, and it looked like it would work, but, it's actually ADDING the numbers; I need it concatenated instead..

Comment: Please use CONCAT method instead, as updated in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting into the same table with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` is no problem at all. MySQL holds the selected rows in a temporary table.